# FCM notification is not removed from notification tray after clicked

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app using `FCM`, and it contains `notification` key in `FCM message body`. Most of devices, when click the `notification`, it's removed from `notification tray`. But, it is not removed in my `Asus Zenpad 8, android 5.0.2` tablet device. This is bug steps:

steps 1:

1. push `notification` A
2. push `notification` B
3. click `notification` A => A not removed from `notification tray`

   4A. -- click `notification` B => both A, B removed from `notification tray`

   4B. -- click `notification` A => Nothing happened, both A, B still kept on `notification tray`.

steps 2:

1. push `notification` A
2. click `notification` A => A not removed from `notification tray`
3. continue click `notification` A => Nothing happened, A still kept on
   `notification tray`.

Is there a solution to set `autoCancel` from `FCM` message, or handle `remove` each `notification` from client side?

Comment: put some code, how you push notification?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have no server code, just show you the bug steps. However, other devices are working normally, so I just want to know what `key`s or `thing`s can make or related to this problem.